# Orientado á objeto: "Undefined reference to" na main.cpp

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, visual-studio-code

Estou começando a POO (Programação Orientada a Objeto) e estou separando os meus atributos e métodos da classe em arquivos diferentes.

Eles estão lendo cada um porém na main.cpp está dando o erro "undefined reference to.. "

O estranho é que quando eu começo a digitar pra usar algum método, ele aparece pra eu escolher como atalho

Estou usando o VS Code;

ps: estou usando marca como int pra teste, pra ver se roda; Se eu escrevo o código normal tudo em um arquivo funciona normal.
.

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "Carro.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

    Carro c1;
    c1.setMarca(3);
    c1.setAno(2018);

    Carro c2;
    c2.setMarca(4);
    c2.setAno(2020);

    cout << c1.getAno() ;


    return 0;
}
```

Carro.cpp:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "Carro.h"


// Marca do carro:
int Carro::setMarca (int marca) { 
    this->marca = marca; 
}

int Carro::getMarca () {
    return marca;  
}


// Ano do carro:
int Carro::setAno (int ano) { 
    this-> ano = ano; 
}

int Carro::getAno () { 
    return ano; 
}
```

Carro.h:

```
#ifndef CARRO_H
#define CARRO_H

#include <stdlib.h>


class Carro {    
    private:
        int ano, marca;

    public:
        int setMarca(int marca);
        int getMarca();

        int setAno(int ano);
        int getAno();    
};

#endif // CARRO_H
```

.

erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

.

reconhecendo no vs code oa atributos na main:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom.. Eu consegui resolver em dois métodos:

```
- Primeiro (errado):
```

Basta tirar o `#include "Carro.h"` do arquivo .cpp e colocar no final do arquivo .h `#include "Carro.cpp"`

Porém o isso não eh recomendado.

O `#include` basicamente puxa o que está escrito naquele arquivo/biblioteca e coloca no lugar. Quando incluímos os as definições dos nossos atributos abaixo dos atributos criados acontece duas coisas:

- Perde a essência da criação de outro arquivo. você pode fazer isso em um arquivo só, sem precisar separar em outros;
- Em projetos maiores pode ter conflitos; Quando coloca o `arquivo.h (ou .hpp)` no início do `arquivo.cpp` vc esta colocando os seus atributos definidos da classe em cima do código, para que embaixo vc possa definir cada atributo. E isso vc pode fazer novamente no `arquivo2.cpp`, definir os atributos e dps configura-los novamente sem que haja interferência.

.

```
- Segundo (certo)
```

Basta colocar o `#include "Carro.h"` no inicio do `arquivo.cpp` e quando for compilar deve mandar compilar os dois arquivos: `main.cpp` e `arquivo.cpp`.

.

.

Nesse video ([inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://youtu.be/DIw02CaEusY)) mostra como depurar um programa em C/C++ simplesmente apertando F5 no VS Code, usei ele pra poder configurar minha compilação.

Para compilar dois arquivos, basta adicionar mais um arquivo no `task.json`:

```
// Meu task.json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "echo",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "main.cpp", 
                "-g",
                "Vetor.cpp",
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\MinGW\\bin"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Perceba que nos meus argumentos ("args") eu coloquei dois arquivos, assim roda normalmente :)

PS: toda vez que vc for depurar (apertar F5) vc precisa colocar o local do(s) arquivo(s) no "args" (o programa vai ser executado em uma janela(terminal) externa). Caso vc queira só rodar o programa precisa baixar uma extensão ("C/C++ Compile Run") e apertar F6 (o programa vai ser executado no próprio terminal do VS Code)

ATENÇÃO: A extensão só roda um único arquivo. Para usar o VS Code para compilar precisar do `task.json` onde vc fala quais arquivos devem ser compilados.

Caso você não queira todo esse trabalho, basta baixar uma IDE que ela já faz tudo isso pra você.

Comment: A solução que você encontrou está errada. Em um projeto pouca coisa maior você vai ter o problema de multiplas definições da mesma função. A propósito qual compilador que você está usando (Clang, Mingw, Gcc)? Você está compilando com comandos no terminal ou está usando o `tasks.json` ou algo que o valha?

Comment: Não entendi o problema que eu teria em multiplas definições. Meu erro era que não estava funcionando essa forma de  programação, separada em três arquivos. Minha dúvida era como fazer a leitura de arquivos um com outro (basicamente) e dessa forma funciona, tudo esta sendo importado pra onde deve.

Pra progrmar eu uso o VS Code, configurei o task.json pra depura e compila e tb instalei uma extensão que direto no terminal.

A compilação é feita pelo Gcc (Mingw), ai configurei o VS Code pra depurar em cima disso.

Comment: A única diferença ,basicamente , entre os tutoriais que eu achei na internet e nos cursos onlines foi de importar o arquivo .cpp no arquivo .hpp (ou .h).
.
Nos tutoriais eh ao contrário, o .cpp importava o .hpp (ou .h)

Comment: O que `#include` faz é basicamente pegar o texto de um arquivo e incluir em outro arquivo. Na prática, o que a solução encontrada por você faz é incluir todas as definições dos métodos da classe Carro abaixo da classe. Isso acaba com todo o propósito de voce ter dois arquivos, pois para todos os efeitos você tem apenas um. E por que isso é um problema? Em um projeto maior, suponha que você tenha mais arquivos do tipo .cpp que você precisa incluir a "Carro.h", cada arquivo desses com a inclusão terá sua própria cópia das definições do método.

Comment: O compilador vai compilar essas definições e quando o linker for reunir o projeto, ele vai encontrar multiplas definições do método e vai reclamar.Isso é sempre assim? Não, no seu caso, o Linker aceitou numa boa porque existe apenas uma unidade de translação. E tambem tem duas exceções importantes que são os templates e as classes com funções inline que devem conter a declaração e a definição em um mesmo arquivo.

Comment: Então, como resolver adequadamente a sua dúvida original, bem, eu sei que é um problema do linker, eu sei que vcê precisa configurar o tasks.json para eke entender que existe mais de um arquivo que precisa ser compilado e linkado, mas, para ser honesto, em C e C++, eu prefiro IDE. Editores de texto, make e agora arquivos json com o VsCode são um pouco mais complicados para configurar e eu evito fazer isso quando posso.

Comment: hmmmmm, entendi!!!!!
Mt obr pela explicação. Vou ver o que eu faço, se eu tento configurar no meu VS Code ou se mudo pra uma IDE. Obr mesmo pela explicação!

Comment: Eu consegui compilar os dois arquivos, arrumei e deixei do jeito normal, colocando o .hpp no .cpp. .. Deixei o código na minha resposta